# Two Factor Authentication with Digital Certificates

Tags: cryptography

I am going to do a Finalyear-project on two-factor authentication,where the second factor as digital certificate with the username/password.I have an idea of doing it for the web applications,how to do this with Java with sample digital certs. and is there any way that i can make use of any Cryptographic algorithms? what are the drawbacks associated with digital certficates?Please give me some details.

Answer (score 0):

The easy approach is to use [x.509 certificates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X.509). Oracle's [Java™ PKI Programmer's Guide](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/certpath/CertPathProgGuide.html) looks like it provides an excellent overview of the Java APIs necessary to use x.509 certificates. Many Java developers use the [Bouncycastle](http://www.bouncycastle.org/) package for additional cryptographic APIs.

The nice part of using x.509 certificates is that nearly everything supports them. You can easily plug x.509 client certificates into most web browsers and most web servers can be easily configured to accept them. Setting up your own [Certificate Authority](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Certificate_authority) is pretty easy with the [TinyCA](http://tinyca.sm-zone.net/) program. (The `openssl` command line tools aren't *awful*, but TinyCA makes it point-and-click easy to get everything right.)

The biggest downside to x.509 is probably the awkwardness involved in setting up your own CA -- so many programs have a list of CA Root Certificates that are baked into the program and supplying your own Root Certificate can be annoying -- somehow you have to transport that file to your clients in a manner that prevents tampering. (A task that would be easier if your CA root were already in the software.)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the guidance.The root certificate is needed for decryption at the client side.Thus i need to install the root certificate in the web server and web browsers(clients) can automatically downloads them?

Comment: The root certificate is needed at the client to _verify_ the server's certificate. Verification is a usual prerequisite before decrypting any traffic from the other peer, though users can use their browser's "Confirm Security Exception" dialog box if they can verify the server's certificate through another mechanism.

Comment: Actually i have not started yet,though my scenario is like this 1)user enters username+password and the think is the Digital cert has to be already loaded in the user system(browser).          2)But without the Digital cert. even the valid person cannot login,thus it achieves the 2nd factor                           3)If the user wants to use the service from any other system,they need to hold the dig.cert with them,only they can login,    otherwise cant login.    How to issue the dig.cert to the user?

Comment: I am going to use the BEA weblogic Dig.certs(Demo purpose) and there utility app known as CertGen to create client certificates.After loading the cert to the browser,the server needs to configure to accept the client cert.

Comment: You've got two big options: generate client certificates for the clients (good for e.g. Key Escrow or severely constrained client systems) _or_ have the clients generate their own certificate signing requests and send the CSRs to the CA. The CA will then hand back a certificate. How you choose to handle all this depends significantly upon your goals for your project.